# Hyperledger Fabric - Error on Invoke / TLS handshake failed with error tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake

Tags: ssl, hyperledger-fabric, handshake

Scope: This is a network with one channel composed of 3 Orgs, 1 anchor peer per organization, 1 CA per org and 1 MSP per org.

I'm facing an issue on my Hyperledger Fabric network related to the TLS handshake process that occurs when I make an invoke call to my chaincode (which is correctly installed and instantiated) through the CLI container.

**ORDERER**

```
[core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 01b TLS handshake failed with error tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake {"server": "Orderer", "remote address": "192.168.0.23:55806"}
```

**CLI**

```
Error: error sending transaction for invoke: could not send: EOF - proposal response: version:1 response:<status:200 >
```

I couldn't find a solution to that so any kind of help would be great.

EDIT: I'm also having warnings like this one in the orderer container when I update the anchor peers:

```
    2018-12-12 14:06:00.518 UTC [common.deliver] Handle -> WARN 014 Error reading from 192.168.32.23:43938: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled
2018-12-12 14:06:00.518 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 016 streaming call completed {"grpc.start_time": "2018-12-12T14:06:00.509Z", "grpc.service": "orderer.AtomicBroadcast", "grpc.method": "Deliver", "grpc.peer_address": "192.168.32.23:43938", "error": "rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled", "grpc.code": "Canceled", "grpc.call_duration": "8.958614ms"}
2018-12-12 14:06:00.518 UTC [orderer.common.broadcast] Handle -> WARN 015 Error reading from 192.168.32.23:43940: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled
2018-12-12 14:06:00.518 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 017 streaming call completed {"grpc.start_time": "2018-12-12T14:06:00.511Z", "grpc.service": "orderer.AtomicBroadcast", "grpc.method": "Broadcast", "grpc.peer_address": "192.168.32.23:43940", "error": "rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled", "grpc.code": "Canceled", "grpc.call_duration": "7.13278ms"}
2018-12-12 14:06:10.328 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 018 streaming call completed {"grpc.start_time": "2018-12-12T14:06:05.692Z", "grpc.service": "orderer.AtomicBroadcast", "grpc.method": "Deliver", "grpc.peer_address": "192.168.32.13:40886", "grpc.peer_subject": "CN=peer1.farmer.supply-chain-network.com,L=San Francisco,ST=California,C=US", "error": "context finished before block retrieved: context canceled", "grpc.code": "Unknown", "grpc.call_duration": "4.636199388s"}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Seems like the orderer was expecting a tls connection but cli did not connect with tls.
Did you properly specify `--tls --cafile <orderer-cert>` during invoke?

Comment: Thank you so much! I fell so embarrassed about missing that I'm also a newbie with Hyperledger Fabric (I've been working with that for 2 weeks). So thanks again! :)

Comment: In hyperledger 2 first-network the cafile used by default is `first-network/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/ca.crt`